# Best practise for read method in ros2 control hw interface for real robots

Tags: ros2-control

so I am trying to implement a ros2 control hw interface for a real robot. The robot communicates over TCP/IP and I can change the protocol.

When I googled how the method read is implemented for real robots, I have two types of solution:

1. sync way - in the read method, there would be an enquiry to the
   hw about its state

   i) example:
   https://github.com/deborggraever/ros2-mecanum-bot/blob/main/mecanumbot_hardware/src/mecanumbot_hardware.cpp

   ii) example:
   https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/galactic-devel/husky_base/src/husky_hardware.cpp

   iii) example:
   https://github.com/joshnewans/diffdrive_arduino/blob/main/src/diffdrive_arduino.cpp
2. async way - there would be a thread reading constantly in
   parallel and the read method would get just the last data
   i) example:
   https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros2/blob/develop/franka_hardware/src/franka_hardware_interface.cpp

So my question is: **What is the best practise? Should I use sync or async approach?**

I am thinking to use async approach because I need as fast communication as I get. Also on the robot side, I have a method which spits out robot position continuously anyway. Any obvious cons?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the option 2 is better even more the communication is through TCP/IP. But I left two comment about it:

1. I recommend to use some try lock approach like the one used in the [realtime buffer implementation](https://github.com/ros-controls/realtime_tools/blob/master/include/realtime_tools/realtime_buffer.h) to not block the read method of your hardware component waiting the second thread to release the mutex
2. Create some logic to check if the last data age meets your delay requirements. As you are always taking the last data, you may do not have clue if in fact this a new data from the robot